# webpack resolve extensions lead to erroneous file names not found at build time

Tags: webpack

I have the following resolve key in my webpack config:

```
resolve: {
        extensions: ["js", "jsx"]
}
```

after running `webpack --display-error-details` i see:

> ERROR in multi main Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or
>   'directory' ./src/index.js in
>   /Users/me/Desktop/coin-web resolve file
>   /Users/me/Desktop/coin-web/src/index.jsjs doesn't exist
>   /Users/me/Desktop/coin-web/src/index.jsjsx doesn't
>   exist resolve directory
>   /Users/me/Desktop/coin-web/src/index.js/package.json
>   doesn't exist (directory description file)
>   /Users/me/Desktop/coin-web/src/index.js is not a
>   directory (directory default file)
>   [/Users/me/Desktop/coin-web/src/index.jsjs]
>   [/Users/me/Desktop/coin-web/src/index.jsjsx]

If I remove the `resolve` key from the config entirely, it builds successfully.  However, I'm curious why its inclusion causes this `jsjs`, `jsjsx` business.

[more context](https://gist.github.com/AlexanderBollbach/d0524dd8b55477917ac46de7608a2070)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because it should be:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
}
```

(Including a period)